# Duality gap in polynomial optimization problem Lasserre relaxation

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, semidefinite-programming, sum-of-squares-method, semialgebraic-geometry

Consider a polynomial optimization problem of the following type

\begin{equation}
 \begin{array}{cl}
 \text{maximize} & p(\mathbf{x}) \\
\text{subject to} & \mathbf{x} \in K \\
\end{array}
\end{equation}

where $p \in \mathbb{R} [x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n]$ is a multivariate polynomial and $K \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is a semialgebraic set (i.e., a set defined by some polynomial inequalities and equalities).

Lasserre introduced a hierarchy of relaxations such that every relaxation has a dual (which is called sum of squares relaxation). If I'm not wrong, the duality gap between this primal and the dual relaxations is zero when $K$ has an interior point and this is a sufficient condition. I'm wondering if there is any other situation such that it makes the duality gap zero between this primal and dual?

For example, in the paper [Strong duality in Lasserre's hierarchy for polynomial optimization](https://arxiv.org/abs/1405.7334), it is said that if $K$ is compact then there is no duality gap but they add new polynomial constraint to $K$ which I think change the Lasserre's relaxation of its dual from.

Comment: This question appears to be research-related. MathOverflow may be a better place to ask it.

Comment: See Section 6.2 of https://homepages.cwi.nl/~monique/files/moment-ima-update-new.pdf